# QSerialPort and Arduino - Handle is invalid - can't connect

Tags: qt, serial-port, arduino

I have problem with my Arduino app in Qt 5.1.1

I have used QextSerialPort and then I wanted to upgrade to QtSerialPort which is a part of Qt5.1.1

The app was working with QextSerialPort.
So I have only changed some things but in core it should be the same. Therefore I am wondering why I can't connect to Arduino.

When asking for errorString() the answer is 'handle is invalid'

This is my code:

```
void MainWindow::init_schnittstelle()
{
    port = new QSerialPort; //create the port

    port->setPortName(schnittstelle); //create the port
    port->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
    port->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    port->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    port->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    port->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);

    port->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Unbuffered); //open the port
    schnittstelleZustand = port->errorString();

    if(!port->isOpen())
    {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "Schnittstelle", "Schnittstelle "+schnittstelle+" reagiert nicht. "+schnittstelleZustand);
    }
    else{
        schnittstelleZustand = ("verbunden");
    }


}
```

In the variable schnittstelle is given the address. I can connect to arduino per Arduino software so I am sure that my Arduino is on COM10 but this says me it is not...

What's wrong?

Comment: Which host OS are you on?

Comment: Ah I have it. The problem is probably by line  if(!port->isOpen()) 
I have to write if(!port->isOpen(QIODevice::ReadWrite))...

Comment: I have tried it under Linux and Win XP

Comment: Clearly you will have to improve your error handling.  Don't ignore the function return values, at a minimum assert() them, use the error() method to obtain an error code.  Some odds you'll find that the port is already in use or doesn't support Unbuffered mode.  Nonstandard ports like "COM10" usually have a driver that requires using the native operating system device name, `"\\\\.\\COM10"`.

Answer (score 1):

I checked Qt documentation and I saw:

> Warning: The mode has to be QIODevice::ReadOnly, QIODevice::WriteOnly, or QIODevice::ReadWrite. Other modes are unsupported.

Change your code

```
port->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Unbuffered);
```

to

```
port->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
```

and try again.

There is documentation link

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qserialport.html#open

Comment: Please, add a link to documentation fragment.

Answer (score 0):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtserialport/qserialport.html#details

> Provides functions to access serial ports.
>
> You can get information
>   about the available serial ports using the `QSerialPortInfo` helper
>   class, which allows an enumeration of all the serial ports in the
>   system. This is useful to obtain the correct name of the serial port
>   you want to use. You can pass an object of the helper class as an
>   argument to the `setPort()` or `setPortName()` methods to assign the
>   desired serial device.

Try enumerating your ports using a `QSerialPortInfo` object, and then print out the port names.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtserialport/qserialportinfo.html#portName

After you have a valid port name, your invalid handle should go away.

Hope that helps.